# Have two different iPhones run code at the same exact time

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, grand-central-dispatch

Currently, the app consists of this - setting a trigger time using `UIDatePicker` and then when this set `NSDate` comes around, play a .mov file. I recently tried running the app on 4 different iOS devices and got pretty terrible results. It appeared as if every device was just slightly out of sync resulting in the music sounding very awkward. However, I occasionally have trials between my iPhone 6S and 6S+ that are almost perfectly in sync. To run the code at a specific time I'm using the following code.

```
let now = NSDate()

let timeDelta = self.appDelegate.triggerDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(now)

let timeDeltaDouble = Double(timeDelta)

print(timeDeltaDouble)

self.delay(timeDeltaDouble) {

    self.player.play()

}
```

Where delay is

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Considering that my results are not very promising, I'm assuming there is a better way of achieving this effect. Would love to learn about a better way to achieve this! And why exactly this method isn't working out.

EDIT: Also, I'm making sure that when the `UIDatePicker` returns a date that the date has seconds set to 0 to keep things uniform.

Comment: You need some networking code to synchronize them, otherwise they'll always be out of sync because their clocks won't match.

Comment: So have them reference some kind of central clock?

Comment: They already synchronize their clocks to a central server, but that's only really accurate to hundreds of milliseconds, and their clocks still drift over time

Comment: You need them to communicate with each other and determine when to go. Relying on the clock alone won't get you very good results.

Comment: I think the real cause of variance vs a central clock is non-deterministic latency in retrieving the time.  This will be a factor -- though a lesser factor -- even if the devices communicate directly.

Comment: Well, are there any resources you guys could point me to so I can learn more about the topic?